# React Helmet: Facebook Open Graph

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

So I've got **`react helmet`** working on my client-side app to re-render `facebook` `og` tags into the head depending on which page is active in the app.

however the `facebook` debugger and `facebook` itself don't pick any of this up. am i missing something ? is this only possible with server-side rendered pages?

i hope not as i'll have to learn `node.js`!

```
 <Helmet>
    <title>{props.title}</title>
    <meta property="og:url" content={ogUrl} />
    <meta property="og:type" content={props.type} />
    <meta property="og:title" content={props.title} />
    <meta property="og:description" content={props.desc} />
    <meta property="og:image" content={ogImg} />
 </Helmet>
```

Comment: Here's another solution. [dynamic OpenGraph tags for SPA React application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62581079/dynamic-opengraph-tags-for-spa-react-application/75234916#75234916)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Most search engines and crawlers use server's response directly, not allowing you to alter it with javascript. So yes, what you need is server-side rendering.

Or, you can use tools like [gatsbyjs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/), [react-static](https://github.com/nozzle/react-static). Basically, they render your components into HTML files beforehand.

Comment: Not the one who downvoted you but it probably should be mentioned that while this is true for Facebook Google DOES wait for up to 10 seconds for everything to load: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Comment: @GokhanSari I wanted to ask will facebook pick up metadata added dynamically with gatsby-helmet?

Comment: @HaseebBurki yes. What gatsby does is that it pre-renders your components on build time (to HTML), so your metadata will be available on page load.

Comment: @GokhanSari I'm afraid I didn't make myself clear. What if I have an online store with different products and an admin panel where vendors can add products themselves. So products detail pages can't be pre-rendered. All the data and metadata will be pulled from the database.

Comment: @HaseebBurki if your data is dynamic, you will need some kind of server rendering since your data will be coming from a server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting your React website statically for example on AWS S3 then you probably don't want Server Side Rendering.

An alternative is using a Lambda Function and returning Pre-rendered HTML to Bots and a dynamic experience to users:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const isBot = (userAgent) => {
  return /bot|googlebot|crawler|spider|robot|crawling/i.test(userAgent);
};

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const userAgent = event.headers['user-agent'];
  const isSearchEngineCrawler = isBot(userAgent);

  if (isSearchEngineCrawler) {
    const preRenderedPath = path.join(__dirname, 'pre-rendered', event.path, 'index.html');
    if (fs.existsSync(preRenderedPath)) {
      const preRenderedHtml = fs.readFileSync(preRenderedPath, 'utf8');
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        },
        body: preRenderedHtml,
      };
    } else {
      return {
        statusCode: 404,
        body: 'Page not found',
      };
    }
  } else {
    const indexHtml = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'), 'utf8');
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      },
      body: indexHtml,
    };
  }
};
```

Beware every request will go through the lambda.

*Also note you can put static html files in the "public" folder in a React website and these can contain the og:image and etc tags and redirect to a dynamic page, eg /shopping/coffee/morroco redirects to /shopping/coffee/#morroco. Unfortunately each time you post a link to FB, the crawler will check/update its cache so you do need something static at the endpoint (you can't upload the html files, force a batch FB link/cache update, then delete the html files).

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can use the [ogtag.me](https://app.ogtag.me) API to send data and create shorten links dynamically with previews and then share this shorten link rather than the link of the actual page.

Comment: Doesn't exist anymore.