# How can i change the title of my website in google search?

Tags: reactjs, google-search

im trying to change the title of my website in google search but i can't seem to find how to do it. I saw something about react-helmet i couldn't figure out how to use it in my files. Im trying to change the title and description of my website and also pages. I made website in react.js and i host it on apache2.

[image: Title]

Comment: React helmet is for social media shares.  Googlebot is more sophisticated and renders your site.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Google Not Showing React-Helmet Title And Description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901741/google-not-showing-react-helmet-title-and-description)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the title and description in the index.html file of our React App and then rebuild the app.

```
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
<meta
  name="description"
  content="**Web site created using create-react-app**"
/>


<title>React App</title>
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi, it does change the title in the tab on the top of my screen but not the title on google.

Comment: This is the only way to update the title, it takes time for google to index the changes made on your page. If you want quick result better  go to Google Search Console website, click on Crawl, the Fetch as Google you can order the page on your website that you are updating to be indexed. Then it might take less time to reflect changes in google search.

Comment: Thanks Tanya! It worked, google just had to index it :)

Comment: Great to help !!