# dynamic OpenGraph tags for SPA React application

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, meta-tags

I want to add some `opengraph` tags for my `create-react-app` powered website. The problem is that when I add them dynamically with something like `Helmet` they are not parsed correctly. Are there any good workarounds for this?

Comment: Show what you tried and what you mean by 'not parsed correctly'

Comment: Are you using the Node server to serve react app?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're managing a web application built with `React` and You may have many **routes** on your application, such as an `/about` page, or `/post/:id` pages where each post has a different content.

For each route, you want to set different **meta** tags, like the title, `description`, `OG image`, and other such things.

You might have used something like React **Helmet** to manage your meta tags within your React code. But the problem is that when a page or post gets shared with `Facebook` or `Twitter`, the crawlers don't run the JavaScript on your site. **They simply take the metatags from the initial bundle.**

This won't do, because you obviously don't want to have the same **metatags** for every page on the entire application. So, you need to dynamically set the meta tags `server-side`, so that the correct previews get shown.

> **Here is an article which gives you step by step process of achieving same:**
> [**Link**](https://www.kapwing.com/blog/how-to-add-dynamic-meta-tags-server-side-with-create-react-app/)

> **And a demo repo here:** [**Repo Link**](https://github.com/justswim/cra-metatag-demo)

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: how would one do this when deployed to an IIS server _without_ node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Another complicated but working method. I faced this same issue. No matter what the backend is if you have server access then the following method can be used.
The following example is based on Apache and Django.

First, you can set up an Apache RewriteCond to redirect requests from Facebook's crawler to a specific URL that returns the dynamic OpenGraph tags. The RewriteCond should check for the Facebook User Agent and exclude any URLs that match the URL of your OpenGraph image.

For example your apache.conf or .httacces can be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|LinkedInBot|Slackbot|TelegramBot) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/metatags
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/metatags$1 [L,R=302]
```

This will redirect requests with a User Agent matching the regular expression facebookexternalhit/[0-9] to https://yourdomain.com/metatags but only if the current request URL does not begin with /media/og.png.

Next, in your Django views, you can create a view function that handles the redirect and extract the OpenGraph tags from the URL parameters. Use the Django HttpResponse class to construct the response with the OpenGraph tags included in the head tag.

For example views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def metatags(request, slug="", *args, **kwargs):
   #Construct the head tag
   meta_tags = extract_meta_tags(slug)
   head_tag = f'<head><title>{meta_tags["title"]}</title>'
   head_tag += f'<meta name="description" content=https://bonusreview.us/>'  
   head_tag += f'<meta property="og:title" content="{meta_tags["title"]}">'  
   head_tag += f'<meta property="og:url" content="https://bonusreview.us/{slug}">'
   head_tag += f'<meta property="og:image" content="https://bonusreview.us/media/og.png">'
   head_tag += '</head>'
   #Return the head tag in the response
   return HttpResponse(head_tag)
```

And your urls.py can be:

```
bonus_hunter_urlpatterns = [
re_path("^metatags/$", views.metatags, name="metatags"),
re_path("^metatags/(?P<slug>.+)/$", views.metatags, name="metatags")]
```