# og:image in facebook preview not Showing , using React-Helmet

Tags: seo, metadata, react-helmet

I am using React-helmet to display metadata for my website. Image previews on Facebook and Twitter are not showing up. The Link for the image is correct . I tried scraping again for Facebook but it didn't work. any suggestions?

```
  <Helmet>
        <title>{`${name}`}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={overview} />
        <meta property="og:title" content={name} />
        <meta property="og:description" content={overview}/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="andromedacryptogalaxy"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content= 
        {`https://www.andromedacryptogalaxy.com/product/${id}`} />
        <meta property="og:image" content={img} data-react-helmet="true"/>
        <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content={img} data-react-helmet="true" />
        <meta name="twitter:title" content={name}/>
        <meta name="twitter:description" content={overview}/>
        <meta name="twitter:image" content={img}/>
        <meta name="twitter:image:alt" content={name}/>
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
        <link rel="canonical" href={`https://www.andromedacryptogalaxy.com/product/${id}`}/>
       </Helmet>


       This is what {img}   returns :  https://cryptools.ge//media/Products/01_7AALrmp.png
```

Comment: I just want to confirm that when you say 'I tried scraping again for Facebook', does this mean that you ran the URL through [Facebook's Debugging Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)?

Comment: If you're using client-side rendering instead of server-side rendering, it [could be causing an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193960/react-helmet-facebook-open-graph).

Comment: No , i clicked scrape again button.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion, i'll research it.